# Stuck at the java code Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

i'm making a sample quiz app with yes no questions, my xml is already done, but i'm really stuck with the java part. i need to display a toast when i click the button, so i can say: you like your phone brand, and when is negative i need to show a toast saying: you don't like your phone brand much. i have all the checkboxes wit ids but i'm really confused now... thanks in advance for the precious help, i appreciate it!

This is the java code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//This is called when tapping the button

public void showResult(View view) {

    CheckBox firstCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes_One);
    boolean isYes = firstCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox firstNCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no_One);
    boolean isNo = firstNCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox secondCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes_Two);
    boolean isYesTwo = secondCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox secondNCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no_Two);
    boolean isNoTwo = secondNCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox thirdCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes_Three);
    boolean isYesthree = thirdCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox thirdNCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no_Three);
    boolean isNoThree = thirdNCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox fourthCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes_Four);
    boolean isYesFour = fourthCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox fourthNCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no_Four);
    boolean isNoFour = fourthNCheckbox.isChecked();
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question? What is the specific problem you are encountering? Questions asking for general help are too broad for this site.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to add an onClickListener to your button and check the check boxes inside, so when you click the button, the app will evaluate your checkboxes and toast accordingly:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        showResult();
    }

    void showResult() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox firstYesCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes_one);
                CheckBox firstNoCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no_one);

                boolean firstYes = firstYesCheck.isChecked();
                boolean firstNo = firstNoCheck.isChecked();

                if (firstYes) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You like phone brand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (firstNo) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You don't like phone brand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, you might consider checking out RadioButton and RadioGroup for a little as well.